# Taking numbers from csv file using labviiew

Tags: string, labview

My program should take all numbers from CSV file put them to array and have some problems.
Have can I take some char of string? Here my program:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7eFfQuRzPgAX3o3WmJIb2dzMFU/view?usp=sharing

Example of csv fie:

1, 2, 3, 4
6, 1, 2, 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is overly complicated. You can load the file using the Read from Spreadsheet file function and simply create a 2D array of the output.

The Read from Spreadsheet function is [polymorphic](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361L-01/lvhowto/selectingdefaultinstpolyvi/). That means you can select what data type it uses. Right-click on the node and select 'Visible Items' and then 'Polymorphic VI Selector'.

Change the pull-down on the bottom of the node to String, and then create a string constant and set it's value to , (comma).

[image: LabVIEW 2011]

Answer (score 0):

please consider using deliminator input on read from spreadsheet VI.

Please check attached[image]

Comment: It takes only first number in every row

Comment: Please consider on deliminator. Might be it is not just "," but comma + space ", " or comma+TAB or comma+two spaces ",  "

Answer (score 0):

The read from spreadsheet file vi is the simplest solution as answered previously. One thing to note about using that function though is that it internally uses the labview error handler with the "Stop" or "Continue" dialog box popup. I've run into the problem where the user cancels out of the file dialog, then sees the error handler dialog box, presses "Stop" and gets confused why the program behaves unexpectedly afterwards.

To prevent this, test the file path using the "File/Directory Info" vi and "Check if File or Folder exists.vi". Put the Read from spreadsheet file in case structure which only runs when the path is not a directory and exists. I tried to attach a snippet to show this, but do not have enough points.